# In Jmeter while trying to test it is showing 401 unauthorize error. tried adding http header manager json extractor authorization manager showing sam

Tags: jmeter, performance-testing, load-testing, unauthorized, jmeter-3.2

In Jmeter while trying to test applicationonly Login page is getting pass next requests it is showing 401 unauthorize error.  tried adding http header manager json extractor authorization managerand encondig base 64 also showing same  401 Un authorized error coming for the requests after login page. please give a solution.

Answer (score 0):

Most probably it means that your login process fails somewhere somehow, and most probably due to missing or improperly implemented [correlation](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.html#correlate-start)

The chance of successful replay of recorded script is kind of minimal because modern web applications/APIs are relying on dynamic parameters for [security reasons.](https://oauth.net/2/bearer-tokens/)

So you need to inspect the network flow of the login sequence, identify all the dynamic parameters, extract them from previous responses using suitable Post-Processors and use relevant [JMeter Variables](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) instead of hard-coded values.

If you have problems with identification of the dynamic parameters you can try out [BlazeMeter Proxy Recorder](https://guide.blazemeter.com/hc/en-us/articles/360000271458-Creating-the-Proxy-Recorder), it is capable of exporting recorded requests in "SmartJMX" mode with automatic detection and correlation of dynamic entities